# Shall I set my current position as "writing master thesis"?

Tags: resume, linkedin, masters

I have started my master thesis and because it is the last leg of my study career and is something quite specific compared to just "following courses", I am thinking to set my current position in Linkedin accordingly. The message that I want to bring across to those that are reading my profile is "ehi, I am almost done, if you are interested in me, get in touch".

Do you think that would make sense?

Moreover, Linkedin would show it as "working here", but I wouldn't consider it working as I am not paid at all, but I am still part of a research group which I am helping (as much as I can..).

So if you answered yes to the previous question, do you think I should list it under "position" or is there something else more appropriate?

Comment: If you are applying to be a cashier at a superstore or something sure... but if you are trying to get a job at a professional do not try to fudge things.

Answer (score 3):

> Do you think that would make sense?

**To me no**. It is an educational project, related to the master courses you are taking.

**It is not an actual job or position in a company**, so it would be confusing to see that as your current position on Linkedin. If you want to express that in your profile consider putting it under other section, perhaps on your description or similar, but not as the "job position" you currently have.

Answer (score 3):

You should not write "writing master's thesis," but you absolutely should have your current position as "M.A. Candidate in _________" (filling in what your degree area of study is in the blank space). The alternative is to leave it blank. The alternative is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would just change your LinkedIn headline to "Masters Candidate in `<topic>` at `<university>`". Being a full-time student isn't the same as full-time employment. Putting the time you were a student as a job on LinkedIn looks very desperate.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

LinkedIn gives you a better position in search results if you show that you're currently employed.

If you want recruiters to find you, be sure to show that you're currently employed — even if it's writing your thesis.

BTW, If you search LinkedIn, you'll find that over 13,000 people list "Thesis" as their current job.

Comment: Unless actually paid to do it, being a master's student **is not** employment, and claiming otherwise is effectively lying to readers.

Comment: LinkedIn doesn't always provide the input field you need to tell your story. Sometimes you have to adapt their system. 

Saying you're writing your thesis when that's what you're doing isn't lying. Please.

Comment: Saying you're employed to write a thesis has very different implications from merely being a student enrolled in a thesis programme.

Comment: I'm more impressed by a candidate who shows they can adapt a system to tell their story than I am by one who will only color within the lines.

Comment: Accurate communication isn't "colouring within the lines". Saying words to mean something when everyone else expects another is an anti-skill.